# Get data from Redux Store after data has been added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, web3js

I am using [a boilerplate called trufflebox's react-auth](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-auth-box/tree/master/src) where

1. `getWeb` is called on loading the page ([Link to code](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-auth-box/blob/master/src/index.js#L22-L29))
2. which creates the `web3` object ([Link to Code](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-auth-box/blob/master/src/util/web3/getWeb3.js#L34-L36))
3. and stores `web3` in the Redux store ([Link to code](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-auth-box/blob/master/src/util/web3/getWeb3.js#L44))

**Problem:** When I retrieve the `web3` object from the Redux store, it is `undefined`, most likely because `web3` has not been created yet in Step 2 described above.

What should be the correct way to retrieve `web3` from the Redux store only after it has been set?

**layouts/test/Test.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import store from '../../store';


class Test extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            web3: store.getState().results.payload.web3Instance
        })
        this.instantiateContract()
    }

    instantiateContract() {
        console.log(this.state.web3)                             // UNDEFINED!!
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Test</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default Test
```

Everything works if I retrieve `web3` again without going to the Redux store:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import getWeb3 from '../../util/web3/getWeb3';


class Test extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        getWeb3
        .then(results => {
            this.setState({
                web3: results.payload.web3Instance
            })
            this.instantiateContract()
        })
    }


    instantiateContract() {
        console.log(this.state.web3)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Test</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Was my answer below able to help point you in the right direction? Please share your progress on this when you can.

Answer (score 4):

Resolve the promise just after creating the store

**src/store.js**

```
        import getWeb3 from './util/web3/getWeb3';
        import { createStore } from 'redux';

        //... prepare middlewares and other stuffs , then : create store
        const store = createStore(/*....configure it as you want..*/);

        // Just after creating store, here the engineering:

        getWeb3.then(results => {
          // Assuming you have suitable reducer
          // Assuming the reducer put the payload in state and accessible via "getState().results.payload.web3Instance"
          store.dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_WEB3', payload: results.payload.web3Instance });
        });


        export default store;
```

In you *./index.js* (where you are rendering the whole app) consider to use `Provider` component as wrapper to pass store behind the seen and have a singleton store.

**src/index.js**

```
        import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
        import store from './store';

        ReactDOM.render(

          <Provider store={store}>
            <Test />
          </Provider>
        )
```

Now, in your component, `connect` HOC will do everything , see comments below  :

**src/.../Test.js**

```
        import { connect } from 'react-redux';


        class Test extends Component {
           // No need any lifecyle method , "connect" will do everything :)

            render() {
                console.log(this.props.web3)      
                return (
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                )
            }
        }
        // Retrieve from Redux STATE and refresh PROPS of component

        function mapStateToProps(state) {
          return {
            web3: state.results.payload.web3Instance  // since you are using "getState().results.payload.web3Instance"
          }
        }
        export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test); // the awesome "connect" will refresh props
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try calling `instantiateContract` during the [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) phase. Check out the following...

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({
    web3: store.getState().results.payload.web3Instance
  });
}

instantiateContract() {
  console.log(this.state.web3); // hopefully not undefined                           
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.whatever) {
    this.instantiateContract();
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <h1>Test</h1>
  )
}
```

where `nextProps.whatever` is what you are mapping from redux (not totally sure what this is given your details). Ideally this is getting fed back into your component and when the value either populates or changes, you then call your function

---

Also, I see a lot of state management here opposed to what I would expect to see done via `props`. if `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` is not a good hook given your application architecture, [componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) could be a viable alternative.

Comment: Do you recommend the `web3` object be retrieved in `index.js` first where the route definitions are, then passing it to the `Test` component as a prop?

Comment: whatever `web3` is, is this one-time app setup stuff you want essentially _before_ you run the app? If so, then totally. I don't know the full architecture of your app, but based on some of your naming I'm leaning towards my hunch being true-ish. I would ditch `.setState` altogether if you can. Dispatch your event, set the value on your store via the _reducer_, map it, and call it a day. If this a true async call, you'll want to leverage a lifecycle event hook to inspect it as I've mentioned above. If you're able to craft it before your app runs, even better as you'll already have it on mount

Comment: @Nyxynyx Were you able to solve this? Please share your progress on this when you can.